# Where is the static function name allocated in C running time environment with SPARC structure?

Tags: c, assembly, sparc

Suppose that this C program is running on a SPARC structure.
I think that normal function's name is allocated in .text, but static one is allocated in BSS? Is that correct?
For example, this is a C static function

```
static void fubar( int b )
{
    static int c = 7;
    void (*d) (int) = fubar;
}
```

Where is this `fubar` stored?

Comment: BSS is all zeroes. You don't store functions there. Zero-initialized static variables may go there though.

Comment: There is no requirement that the name be stored at all. If it's stripped of debugging symbols, there is no need for storing the name. Function names only matter at compile time, for exported functions, and debugging purposes (and the name isn't strictly necessary for debugging; a debugger with source access could look it up in the source file); a static function's name is meaningless programmatically the moment it finishes compilation.

Comment: Please put the question in the question, not just the title. The question shouldn't start with "and".

Comment: "name is stored in .text". No it's not. There are no function names in the text section - static or otherwise.

Comment: The code for `fubar` goes into `.text`. The name `fubar` is not stored anywhere (see comments above). The variable `d` is local on the stack (unless optimized to a register, or elided completely).

Comment: @Jester But is there any memory is allocated for the function name? If so, where?

Comment: No, there isn't. See ShadowRanger's comment, above. This applies to non-static functions just the same.

Comment: If you don't strip the binary, the names may be stored in debug info, but that's probably not even loaded by OS when executing the binary, it's just in the executable file. There's no need to have the function name anywhere in the machine code, it needs only memory address of it.